Conditional probability given three events and a complement
I am given specific values of P(A, B, C) and P(AC, BC, AB) and P(ABC). I derived a formula for the following: P(BC|A or C) to be $$\frac{P(B^C∩(A or C))}{P(A or C)}$$. I can find the complement of B using 1-P(B). I can expand (A or C) using the inclusion-exclusion/addition formula as P(A) + P(C) - P(A∩C). My question is, why does BC get multiplied in the numerator to (A or C)? I know not every time there is an intersection you multiply, which is why I got stuck because that is the case here. I don't understand what is independent and what is dependent here.
Also, could I have expanded it like so? :  $$\frac{P((B^C∩A) or (B^C∩C))}{P(A or C)}$$And then used the difference rule P(BC∩A) = P(A) - P(B∩A) to find the associated intersections with the complement since I have P(AB, BC)? Trying this did not give me the correct answer, and I'm unsure why.

Unless you know (or assume) there is independence, you cannot say $P(A \cap B)=P(A), P(B)$.  For this question, I doubt you should assume independence.

$P(A \text{ or } C) = P(A \cup C) = P(A)+P(C)-P(A \cap C)$ by inclusion-exclusion.  Similarly $P(B^c \cap(A \text{ or } C)) = P(B^c \cap A)+P(B^c \cap C)-P(B^c \cap A\cap C)$.  Perhaps if you edited your question to include the numbers and your calculations, somebody might look at them.

As the comments of Henry indicated, you should not be attempting multiplication when computing (for example) $~P(A \cap B).~$  Beyond that, I suggest the following shortcut:  $$p[ ~B^c ~| ~(A \vee C) ~] + p[ ~B ~| ~(A \vee C) ~] = 1.$$  That is, assuming that the event $~(A \vee C)~$ has occurred, either the event $~B~$ also occurred or the event $~B^c~$ also occurred.  Then, the use of Inclusion-Exclusion becomes straightforward, because each of the terms in the following expression is (apparently) known: $$P(AB) + p(BC) - p(ABC).$$

@user2661923 Thanks, my question is, and I'm not sure if this makes sense, but for P(B and (A or C)), why could I not have expanded it as P((B and A) or (B and C))? That was my initial thought and it was wrong. I see how I could have used the inclusion-exclusion though.

@Aqq If I understand your question correctly, it is because the event $~(A \vee C)~$ is actually equal to the events $~[ ~(A) + ~(C) - ~(A \wedge C) ~].$  Therefore, the event $~[ ~B \wedge ~( ~A \vee C ~) ~] ~$ is actually equal to $$[ ~B \wedge A ~] + [ ~B \wedge C ~]  -[ ~B \wedge ( ~A \wedge C ~) ~].$$
